# Blank React Githubpages Page

Tags: reactjs, hosting, github-pages

I've created a website locally and my plan was to deploy on Gh pages. But it's just blank.

My repo can be found here: https://github.com/JulianGrafen/crypto-website

I've tried almost everything:

1. Changed The BrowserRouter to HashRouter
2. Added  `"predeploy": "npm run build","deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"` to the package.json
3. Tried this basename in Router: `<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`
4. And of course followed all steps to deploy a project on gh pages